# Automatic insertion of data into another related tables

Tags: sql-server

In my example project, I have 3 tables chaining each other up with keys. What I have in mind right now is that they can update and be automatically updated every time I insert a record in any of them.
For example,

```
TableA ={
   Guid id (PK), Guid AId, int AVal, Guid BId(FK references BId)
}
TableB ={
   Guid id (PK), Guid BId, int BVal
}
TableAB={
   Guid id (PK), Guid AId (FK references TableA's AId), Guid BId (FK references TableB's BId)
}
```

If I insert one into `TableA`, I think a new row in `TableB` and `TableAB` would be created automatically without `Trigger`. I am currently writing this example project in PHP, and I have to add lines of code to insert data into tables manually.
What is the meaning of `relational` then? That I create their relationship and manipulate it myself sounds a bit spoilt, doesn't it?

Comment: *"If I insert one into `TableA` and `TableB`, I think a new row in `TableAB` would be created"* So you *assume* that everything in table A and Table B is related? If I have a table, `CustomerOrder` and a table `Item` then a should a row for *every* `CustomerOrder` and `Item` be created in the `OrderItem` table? No. Because there *is* a relationship doesn't mean every row *has* to have one. A Customer can have no orders, or an Item could *never* be ordered.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you a lot, that clarifies my doubt. I thought when a relationship with keys is created, everything (e.g. insertion, update, deletion) is automatically done by the SqlServer agent. I mean now that when a customer wants to update their cart, I have to write code to update other related tables I once thought the server would do it for me.

Comment: SQL Server Agent has *nothing* to do with it. That is a separate scheduling tool that is included in SQL Server Standard (or higher) Editions. If relationships were required to be built by Agent, then Express, Azure SQL Database, and LocalDB would all be broken, as none of those have SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Oh awesome! BTW how is an Azure database different from a local database? If you are presented with 2 databases, what will you do to define one from the other?

Comment: *"how is an Azure database different from a local database?"* That is a completely different question; though there is a wealth of resources if you search on your favourite search engine.

Comment: I only mean to learn how. I think there should be something inside that makes them distinguishable.

Comment: One is in the cloud, one is local; that's a distinguishing feature to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to make the insert data manually.
In the database, the Foreign Key concept is used to prevent invalid data from being inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the values contained in the parent table.

Answering your second question,
Relational here means that the databases are based on the relational model, a straightforward way of representing data in tables.

In a relational database, each row in the table is a record with a unique ID called the key. The columns of the table hold attributes of the data, and each record usually has a value for each attribute, making it easy to establish relationships among data points.

Comment: Thank you Basiir, how necessary is it to have databases with relationships set up? I think the programmers can read from and write to the tables and display the records even when the tables have no relationships at all.

Comment: It is not necessary. It depend on the user requirement and the team plan to develop the database. You can start on making simple to do list, blog, ecommerce project to understand better about the database concept.